# Regex: How to catch numbers in (1, 2) (1,1)(1 , 1)

Tags: regex

```
((\\d+)[x](\\d+))
```

Do I need to write every condition `((\\d+)[x] (\\d+)) | ((\\d+) [x] (\\d+))` ...

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by every condition?

Comment: Do you mean different amounts of space around the numbers?

Comment: Shouldn't `[x]` be `,`?

Comment: Please attach sample inputs with expected outputs.

Comment: Your issue was not clearly stated. Could you present your expected output?

Comment: @Barmar yes, possible outputs 1 2 / 1 1 / 1 1.. I'm looking for a smarter regex pattern

Comment: What is the sample input? The title contains `(1,2)`, but the regexp matches `(1x2)`. Also, you need to escape the parentheses if you want them to match literally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to have optional spaces around `[x]`. If that is just a single optional space you could use `\s?` and if you want to match zero or more spaces you can use `\s*`.

Comment: Try \(\d\s?,\s?\d\)
assuming a single digit and a possible single space